# AngularJs how do I write a http put request by id for two tables that are connected by a foreign key? entityframework 6 and web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, web-services

I have a table A and table B in ms sql. I wrote this as follows

```
    var request = $http({
        method: 'put',
        url: urlBase + '/intervieweeDetails/' + empToUpdate.id,
        data: empToUpdate
    });

    return request;
```

Even if I manually write a json for table B and add to empToUpdate object, it always throws an exception

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Attaching an entity of type 'IntervieweeServiceJoin.Models.intervieweeExtra' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.'

Is my http method write? Getting and adding are working fine but I cannot update the values at all

```
    // PUT: api/intervieweeDetails/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutintervieweeDetail(int id, intervieweeDetail intervieweeDetail)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != intervieweeDetail.id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(intervieweeDetail).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!intervieweeDetailExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

The exception is caught in

```
        db.Entry(intervieweeDetail).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: This sounds like a Backend Issue and not a AngularJS issue.  Suggest re-tagging to whatever backend service you are using to get a proper answer.

Comment: @MichaelLynch Yes thanks. I have edited the question

Comment: Perfect.  Hopefully now it can reach those who know more about asp.net and you can get an answer :D

Comment: Can you post your entity framework query? Basically an object already exists in that db context with that ID

Comment: @MikeS I updated the question